# TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null when running tests

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I get the following error when running my tests : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null`. However it should not be null but an empty string.

If I start the application I do not get this error. Only when running the tests written in jest typescript and react testing library.

The application:
When clicked on the button, it will call the following api : https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1. Then it shows the title in the react app. That's it.

MultipleFetches.tsx

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {CallAPI} from '../API/useAPI';

interface State{
    postResponse :{
        data:{
            userId: number,
            id: number,
            title: string,
            body:string
        },
        success : boolean,
        error: null
    }
}

interface PostResponse{
   
}

class MultipleFetches extends React.Component{
    
    state : State = {
        postResponse:{
            data: {
                userId:0,
                id:0,
                title : "",
                body : ""
            },
            success: false,
            error : null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      
    }

    handleOnClick =() =>{
        CallAPI("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1").then(res =>{
            this.setState({
               postResponse : res
            })
        })
    }

    render() : React.ReactNode{
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Fetch API Multiple Times</h1>
                <button data-testid="post-click" onClick={this.handleOnClick}>Click to fetch data</button>
                <p><b>Post Title</b></p>
                <p data-testid="post-title">{this.state.postResponse.data.title}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MultipleFetches;
```

MultipleFetches.test.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, waitForElement, getByTestId, wait, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";


import MultipleFetches from "../components/MultipleFetches";

describe("<MultipleFetches/>", () =>{
    test("post shows correct title after button click", async () =>{
        const utils = render(<MultipleFetches/>)
        
        const data ={
            userId: 1,
            id: 1,
            title: "Mock Title",
            body: "Mocked Body"
        }

        // I don't even know what this does??
        global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => data);

        jest.spyOn(global,'fetch')
        .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({
            json: () => Promise.resolve(data)
        } as Response))
    
        const button = utils.getByTestId("post-click");
        fireEvent.click(button);
        const newPostTitle = await waitFor(() => utils.getByTestId("post-title"))
        expect(newPostTitle.textContent).toBe("Mock Title");

    })
})
```

useAPI.ts

```js
const returnResponse ={
    data: null,
    success: false,
    error: null
}

export async function CallAPI(url : string){
    try{
        const response = await fetch(url);
        if ( response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) throw new Error("Failed to fetch");
        if(response.status === 200){
            const json = await response.json();
            returnResponse.data = json;
            returnResponse.success = true
        }
    }
    catch(e){
        returnResponse.error = e.message
    }

    return returnResponse;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you missed to set `status` as part of response while your api code is now checking that. The right mock is supposed to be:

```js
jest.spyOn(global,'fetch')
  .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({
      status: 200, // add your status here
      json: () => Promise.resolve(data)
  } as Response))
```

Comment: Ah :) I've just checked & figured out that we talked in the past :) Nice to see you again. Happy new year

Comment: Haha nice to see you too :D. Happy new year for you too!